# Python reading from file vs directly assigning literal

Tags: python, newline

I [asked a Python question minutes ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65167898/python-n-newline-character-representation) about how Python's newline work only to have it closed because of another question that's not even similar or have Python associated with it.

I have text with a '\n' character and '\t' in it, in a file. I read it using

```
open().read()
```

I then Stored the result in an identifier. My expectations is that such a text e.g

```
I\nlove\tCoding
```

being read from a file and assigned to an identifier should be same as one directly assigned to the string literal

```
"I\nlove\tCoding"
```

being directly assigned to a file.

**My assumption was wrong anyway**

```
word = I\nlove\tCoding
```

ends up being different from

```
word = open(*.txt).read()
```

Where the content of *.txt  is exactly same as string "I\nlove\tCoding"

**Edit:**

I did make typo anyway, I meant \t && \n , searching with re module's search() for \t, it return None, but \t is there. Why is this please?

Comment: _read from a file and assigned to an identifier should be same_: What makes you think the text is **not** the same ?

Comment: Printing the result of the string assigned as literal results in newline and tab.       Whereas for word=open(file. txt).read(), printing word doesn't include newline and tab

Comment: Please any help will be appreciated, also re.search('\t',file) where file is the file containing the string above, None is returned

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to differentiate between newlines/tabs and their corresponding escape sequences:

```
for filename in ('test1.txt', 'test2.txt'):
    print(f"\n{filename} contains:")
    fileData = open(filename, 'r').read()
    print(fileData)

    for pattern in (r'\\n', r'\n'):
        # first is the escape sequences, second the (real) newline!
        m = re.search(pattern, fileData)
        if m:
            print(f"found {pattern}")
```

Out:

```
test1.txt contains:
I\nlove\tCoding
found \\n

test2.txt contains:
I
love    Coding
found \n
```

Answer (score 1):

The string you get after reading from file is `I\\nlove\\nCoding`.If you want your string from literal equals string from file you should use `r` prefix. Something like this - `word = r"I\nlove\nCoding"`

Comment: word = open("tmp.txt")
print(re.search('\\t',word.read())).   Returns None

Comment: tmp.txt = "I\nlove\tCoding"